# "No rows found" when there's no are row /cells for UICollectionView and UITableView

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, uicollectionview

Was wondering how to properly display a notification or text when there are no rows / cells found on my `UICollectionViewController` and `UITableViewController`. At this time I would only show a `UIAlertView`, is there a better way to approach this?

```
UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc]
initWithTitle:@"Warning!" 
message:@"No rows found" 
delegate:self
cancelButtonTitle:@"Logout"];

[alert show];
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I personally use the `UICollectionView` footer to show this kind of messages. I make a footer in the Story Board(`Section Footer` selected in the attribute inspector of the story board) with a label with the message and then in the `UICollectionViewController`:

```
- (UICollectionReusableView *)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView viewForSupplementaryElementOfKind:(NSString *)kind atIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    UICollectionReusableView *reusableview = nil;

    if (kind == UICollectionElementKindSectionFooter) {
        reusableview = [collectionView dequeueReusableSupplementaryViewOfKind:UICollectionElementKindSectionFooter withReuseIdentifier:@"FooterView" forIndexPath:indexPath];

        if(images.count>0){
            reusableview.hidden = YES;
            reusableview.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 0, 0);
        }else{
            reusableview.hidden = NO;
            reusableview.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, self.view.frame.size.width, self.view.frame.size.height);
        }

    }

    return reusableview;
}
```

Comment: I think I went with this but used the header instead. Would footer make more sense?

Comment: I use footer because the header adds me extra space I am not able to get rid off.

Comment: It may be worth stating (as I had this problem when I implemented your solution) that when you add the Section Footer to your `UICollectionView` from the Storyboard, you also need to give the footer an identifier. This is in the Attributes list under "Collection Reusable View". In @Mingot 's  example the identifier is "FooterView". Really helpful solution!

Comment: there is an issue for this approach that becasue you need to set the footer height in - (CGSize)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView layout:(UICollectionViewLayout*)collectionViewLayout referenceSizeForFooterInSection:(NSInteger)section , so when there is a record, though you hide the footer, footer's space is still there, which will leave blank space at the bottom when scrolling.

Answer (score 13):

UICollectionView (and UITableView) has a property named backgroundView.
You can create a view with a label, and just play with the hidden property of it.

I actually use this technic to show the "no rows" label and the "loading" label.

Comment: This is the simplest and easiest solution. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

As mentioned by @tal952, you can use `backgroundView` property of `UICollectionView` or `UITableView` if entire collectionView/tableView is empty.

Here is what I use, the same can be applied to tableView as well:

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    if myArray.isEmpty && collectionView.backgroundView == nil {
        let noItemLabel = UILabel() //no need to set frame.
        noItemLabel.textAlignment = .center
        noItemLabel.textColor = .lightGray
        noItemLabel.text = "No item present"
        collectionView.backgroundView = noItemLabel
    }

    collectionView.backgroundView?.isHidden = !myArray.isEmpty
    return myArray.count
}
```

If you have footers or headers present, set their `isHidden` property accordingly:

```
footer.isHidden = self.myArray.isEmpty
```

[image: empty collectionView/tableView]

Answer (score 1):

Use this Tweet box info like alert. its catchy 
[Tweet like info Panel](https://github.com/MugunthKumar/MKInfoPanelDemo)

Comment: this looks cool, but I would like to have some kind of permanent text on there like what @brhane was recommending. i am sure i'd end up using this as well. thanks btw!

Answer (score 0):

Create a UIView that has a label that says "No rows found" (_noRowsView). Then use that as a tableHeaderView when the number of rows is 0.

```
-(void)dataLoadingDidFinish {
   if(_data.count == 0) {
       self.tableView.tableHeaderView = _noRowsView;
   } else {
      self.tableView.tableHeaderView = nil;
   }

}
```

Comment: it doesn't seem to be the same with collectionviews, thoughts?

Answer (score 0):

The best answer is in [How to change the UICollectionView footerview's height programatically](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27865301/how-to-change-the-uicollectionview-footerviews-height-programatically)

change the reusableview.frame in viewForSupplementaryElementOfKind is never working. It is misleading to mark the kahlo's reply as the correct answer.